# How do I determine what kind of error ajaxError is handling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, exception

I'm trying to handle AJAX errors in a web application that uses jQuery.

I'm setting up an event handler to deal with AJAX errors like this:

```
$('body').ajaxError(error_handler);
```

However, despite the information that's passed to that handler, I'm finding it difficult to determine what sort of error occured.

The two errors I'm interested in identifying are:

- When the application server is down
- When I've used `$.getJSON(...)` and the response isn't parsable as JSON data.

Both of these cause my error handler to fire, but I need to handle each error differently, and don't know how I can do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequest` is the second argument to the function. You can check the `status` property to get the HTTP status code. That should tell you if you got a valid response in an unexpected format or if the server is down.